# Is there a way to use terraform on Google Cloud to build VMs with Python and Python libs installed?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'd like to create a terraform script to build developer VMs with Python and DB connection libs already installed.

Searches show using sudo apt-get, but that method produces errors.  Google searches divert to running terraform from python :)

Comment: Please make sure to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: If you mention an error in your question, include the error message.

Comment: There are several methods to use Terraform. The HCL can wait for the instance to start, connect via SSH, and then execute shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

You have several way to achieve this:

- Create a container with all the lib that you want and create [a compute engine with the container](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers)
- Create a VM with a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux) that add the library to your VM
- Create a VM, add the libraries and create an [image of the disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-custom). Then create a VM with this [custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#custom_images).

But, if it's a developer VM you can also have a look to Cloud Workstation. You can also create a [workstation](https://cloud.google.com/workstations?hl=en) images with all the libraries installed on it (and its designed for that!)